# How to store PostgreSQL state in Docker hosts

Tags: linux, macos, postgresql, docker, filesystems

PostgreSQL's handling of it's data folder is not compatible with Docker's host mounted folders.

It might work under Linux with ext4 file systems mounted, but on OS X or Windows, when running

```
docker run -it --rm -v `pwd`/test:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

initdb terminates in random disk write errors like:

```
creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ... 
FATAL:  could not write to file "pg_xlog/xlogtemp.25": Input/output error
```

or

```
FATAL:  could not close file "base/1/1249": Input/output error
FATAL:  could not close file "base/1/2603": Input/output error
CONTEXT:  writing block 0 of relation base/1/1247
```

When using named volumes, it all works well, however named volumes are not really a safe way to keep data. For example in Docker for Mac they are all hidden inside a huge qcow2 virtual disk image.

What strategy do you recommend for keeping a PostgreSQL's state in non-Linux hosts?

Should I be saving a backup every n minutes into a mounted folder and check for the data folder on startup and restore from backup if needed? Or should I just rsync between a named volume and a host mounted volume? Are there any projects / Docker files which solved this?